# Different style for TinyMCE in edit mode with diazo turned on

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm creating a theme with Diazo for plone4. I noticed that TinyMCE when in edit mode doesn't respect the style of the site. It seems more "raw" with basic font and header style (h1, h2, etc).

What's wrong?

Thank's

Comment: I suppose that the problem is the iframe called via tinymce

Comment: I'd say you suppose correctly. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE sets up the content to be edited in an iframe and loads a stylesheet called @@tinymce-getstyle, which is actually a browser view that includes the stylesheets that are registered in portal_css.

I've had the most success with Diazo when I register my stylesheets in the Plone stylesheet registry (portal_css), and then add Diazo rules to copy them into the head of my theme.

Disadvantage:

- You can no longer edit the theme on its own apart from running via Plone.

Advantages:

- The stylesheets are automatically merged and compressed.
- TinyMCE can load the styles.

Comment: another disadvantage: you can no longer use state of the art front end tools like grunt and related to work on your stylesheets. Not to mention sass/less compilation etc.

Comment: Yes you can. A resource registered in portal_css can live on the filesystem and be built however you like.

Comment: yes you are right. Although I have been using grunt and bowerInstall and usemin to inject resources into my diazo index.html, but then tinymce will not get hold of them. So in this case I needed to also serve the css via portal_css for tiny.